# 2-color scale option in excel not working?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to do very simple thing, In screenshot for

> People->General cell

I have defined a condition as

> People tab cell G3<2 color is minimum and 
>   People tab cell G3>>4 color is maximum of [image: here]

I have no Idea, why the cell doesn't change color.

Comment: You're formula isn't clear from your question, but it seems you follow a wrong approach.  Min and max fields requires the min and max values, but you entered a formula with `IF` which can evaluate to true or false (1 or 0) only.

Comment: You can simply write =People!$G$3<2 under Minimum and =People!$G$3>4 under Maximum

Comment: It won't work, I'm trying another approach but no results. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031267/copy-background-color-from-one-cell-to-cell-in-separate-sheet-using-ms-excel/38032155?noredirect=1#comment63505889_38032155

Comment: Please clarify what are you trying to do so the community can better assist you.

Comment: The formula for the maximum in the screen grab shows `...Peo+$G$3...` but surely this should be `...People!$G$3...`.    That aside the comment above that the IF statements are not required is correct.

Comment: I think the main problem is probably that you have used absolute references  `...$G$3...` instead of relative references `...G3...`.    The conditional format will only be evaluating $G$3 regardless of the range you have in the "Applies To" field.

Comment: I tried that and my suggestions won't work but I have a solution which I will post.

Comment: The formula must return a number, date, or time value.  This is explained in the Excel help (my version is 2010)
Since either an IF statement or other boolean functions return true/false, they will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Given the number of people has to be a whole number  <2 is equivalent to <=1.  To do this just use the "Number" option in the conditional formatting as per the screen grab.

[image]

Note: The formula must return a number, date, or time value. This is explained in the Excel help (my version is 2010) Since either an IF statement or other boolean functions return true/false, they will not work.